# Ruby on rails-Tabular form for input taken from user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to print in tabular form the entries given by user. The table will contain 3 columns for name,registration number and classes attended, however the output is not as expected. Its first printing all the names and then all the registration numbers and so on. I want to print a name and the registration number according to name and classes attended.

```
</head><table width="100%">
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>REGISTRATION NUMBER</th>
<th>CLASSES ATTENDED</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<% @name_students.each do |t| %>
<th><%= t.name_student %></th><br>
<% end %>
<% @reg_nos.each do |t| %>
<th><%= t.reg_no %></th><br>
<% end %>
<% @classes_ats.each do |t| %>
<th><%= t.classes_at %></th><br>
<% end %>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my controller action.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
def home
@name_students = Page.all
@reg_nos = Page.all
@classes_ats = Page.all
end
def list
@name_students = Page.all
@reg_nos = Page.all
@classes_ats = Page.all
end
def add
Page.create(:name_student => params[:nam])
Page.create(:reg_no => params[:reg])
Page.create(:classes_at => params[:cls])
redirect_to :action => 'home'
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing, you should probably have `PagesController#home` return something like `@pages = Page.all` object and display the data kind of like this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Registration Number</th>
    <th>Classes Attended</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <% @pages.each do |p| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= p.name %></td>
      <td><%= p.registration_number %></td>
      <td><%= classes_attended(p.classes_attended) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Above, `classes_attended(p)` is a call to a helper method that you would use to map the class names of the classes that student attended into an display-able array.  Really, that kind of display logic might be better in a decorator, but a helper method should be fine for now.

Let me know if I've totally misunderstood what you're doing, and I'll delete my answer.

Edit to add:

Example index method:

```
def home
  @pages = Page.all
end
```

Also, looking at your question again, is there a reason you're creating three `Page` objects with one attribute each instead of one `Page` object with all three attributes?  It should probably look something like `Page.create(:name_student => params[:nam], :reg_no => params[:reg], :classes_at => params[:cls])`.  That's pretty much the only way the solution I posted will work.  Again, though, I might be totally misunderstanding what you're going for.

Comment: It was really helpful but can you please add your controller content too?

Comment: @shreyash Added a couple of things.